# How to use different constructor based on input inside LinQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to call different constructors inside a foreach loop based on a predetermined input.

This is what I currently have but i got quite a a rat tail on some parameters, which just causes a lot of identical code.

```
if(true)
{
 XYZ.ToList().ForEach(xyz=> foo.AddBar(new Bar(a, b.ToList().Find(xyz))))
} else 
{
 XYZ.ToList().ForEach(xyz=> foo.AddBar(new Bar(b.ToList().Find(xyz))))
}
```

If possible I would like to have something like this:

```cs
XYZ.ToList().ForEach(xyz=> foo.AddBar(new Bar(true ? a : null, b.ToList().Find(xyz))))
```

Passing params seems unfeasible, because of the forEach loop or am I mistaken?
Edit:
class constructor:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo a) { ... }
    public Bar(Foo a, Baz b) { ... }
    public Bar(Foo a, Baz b, Qux c) { ... }
}
```

In the end the Bar gets serialized with XmlSerialization so id like to avoid null parameters

Comment: So `Bar` is your own class and you can define appropriate constructors? And I don't see any conflict between `ForEach` and the way your constructors are defined (`params` or not).

Comment: Unless you show all relevant variables, parameters and constructors, you're going to get very generic answers. The Linq part also isn't very relevant.

Comment: I think this is hard to answer without seeing what/where exactly the "rat tail on some parameters" really is. The code you posted could for example be optimized by createing `b.ToList().Find()` _outside_ the lambda before the `if`. If that's not possible because of the parameters, than your question is not answerable without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @RenéVogt I edited my question, its not possible to define before the loop, because im using xyz for the queries. The rat tail just consist of nested queries that i dont think are relevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a class `Bar` with multiple constructors with many parameters:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo a) { ... }
    public Bar(Foo a, Baz b) { ... }
    public Bar(Foo a, Baz b, Qux c) { ... }
}
```

And you want to call the constructors conditionally. One approach would be to create a factory method (or class) where you prepare the parameters you'll definitely need:

```
Bar GetBar(...)
{
    var foo = GetFoo(...);

    if (flag)
    {
        var baz = GetBaz(...);
        return new Bar(foo, baz);
    }

    return new Bar(foo);
}
```

Alternatively, alter the constructors so you'll have one remaining, accepting null parameters for the rest:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo a, Baz b, Qux c) { ... }
}
```

Then simply call it with values or nulls:

```
var foo = GetFoo(...);
var baz = flag1 ? GetBaz(...) : null;
var qux = flag2 ? GetQux(...) : null;

var bar = new Bar(foo, baz, qux);
```

Comment: id like to avoid tangling with the constructor if possible. Also the classes are getting serialized into HTML so im not sure if calling it with null params would cause a serialization into the file if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can have one constructor with all parameters

```
public class Bar
{

    Bar(TypeOfA? a, TypeOfB? b, TypeOfC? c...)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {}
        ....
    }
}
```

and call with

```
XYZ.ToList().ForEach(xyz=> foo.AddBar(new Bar(a, b.ToList().Find(...))))
```

but in this case, you move the if conditions from one part of code to another one and you have a constructor with parameters that receive null.
I think it's much better use many constructors and

```
if(true)
{
 XYZ.ToList().ForEach(xyz=> foo.AddBar(new Bar(a, b.ToList().Find(...))))
} else 
{
 XYZ.ToList().ForEach(xyz=> foo.AddBar(new Bar(b.ToList().Find(...))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [?: Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and change constructor conditionally

```
XYZ.ToList().ForEach(xyz=> foo.AddBar(true? new Bar(a, b.ToList().Find(...)) : new Bar(b.ToList().Find(...)) ))
```

Comment: this sadly doesnt solve my problem of having a lot of code twice, because most of it is connected to the other params, which i still would have to pass twice

Comment: You can refactor the "b.ToList().Find(...)" to a new method and call the method from both cases. You can select the section you want to refactor in Visual Studio and press [CTRL+R CTRL+M](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-method?view=vs-2019) to extract method

Comment: yeah thats the only solution i could find too, even tho i dont like to have an extra function for this specific query. If no one else has a better solution im going to accept this. Btw thanks for the refactor tip, that was new for me